# How do I use FFmpeg and OpenAI Whisper to transcribe a RTMP stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, transcription

I have been able to use FFmpeg with OpenAI Whisper to transcribe an audio file to text.

What I would like to do is, instead of using a pre-recorded file, stream an RTMP feed into FFmpeg in order to transcribe in real-time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with [this shell script](https://gist.github.com/reasonableperson/a539cdeea34f4aba9ef5f15d0927d0c1), which requires you to have `ffmpeg`, `inotifywait` and `whisper` installed:

```
ffmpeg -i STREAM_URL -f segment -segment_time 30 -strftime 1 %s.mp4 -v verbose 2>&1 |
  grep -Po --line-buffered "Opening '\K\d+" |
  xargs -I _ bash -c 'echo; date -d @_; inotifywait -qqe CLOSE _.mp4; whisper --model medium.en _.mp4'
```

The `ffmpeg` command saves 30-second segments to the current directory in mp4 format, named by Unix timestamp. Its output is then filtered for the debug messages that are printed when it opens a segment file for writing. The command will print the time when each segment file is opened, wait for `ffmpeg` to close it, and then call `whisper`.